# Desktop computer won't boot after BIOS changes

Tags: boot, desktop-computer, post

I have an iBuyPower desktop that is a couple years old. I was doing windows updates and it notified me that my computer didn't support windows 11 due to no trusted platform module. (Warning, idiocy ahead).  I booted into the BIOS and found an Intel trusted something or other setting that was disabled.  I enabled it.  Now my computer won't boot. I just get a weird graphical glitch and then it goes away and nothing.  Fans still spin. No post beeps.  Nothing.

[image]

Other things I changed:

- Disabled Overclocking
- Disabled "full screen boot"
- Enabled "beep on boot"

Motherboard: Z370 IB-R

Comment: *"an Intel trusted something or other setting"* ... Was it `Intel Trusted Execution Technology`?

Comment: That sounds right. :(

Comment: And POST fails so you cannot get to the BIOS/UEFI screen?

Comment: What's in the screen capture is all I see. I've tried spamming F8, F9, F12, DEL.  Nothing different happens. The glitch appears for about 3 seconds then it goes black again. No beeps.

Comment: You'll need to clear the CMOS. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025368/processors.html

Comment: Oh man, I haven't done that in 20 years.  Thanks for jogging the memory! Will report back.

Comment: I didn't have a jumper and there were none on the board, so I shorted it with a screwdriver and turned it on. I got a *readable* notice that the memory had been reset! Looks good, buuut, while it was open I noticed a LOT of dust so I'm going to the store to buy some canned air and thermal paste. Will accept answer tomorrow once I confirm everything :D

Comment: There hasn’t been an answer submitted to accept

Comment: @Ramhound oops, I should have put that as an answer and not a comment. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now my computer won't boot. I just get a weird graphical glitch and then it goes away and nothing. Fans still spin. No post beeps. Nothing.

If changes to BIOS/UEFI settings caused the computer to fail POST, clearing the CMOS (either with a jumper or by removing the CMOS battery for 5 minutes then reseating) will restore the settings to factory defaults.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025368/processors.html